# getting time of image capture using camera2

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I want precise time of image-capture in nanoseconds/milliseconds using `Camera2` with the base of `System.currentTimeMillis()` and not in `SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()`

Comment: In your callback that receives the image, find the current time, using `System` or `SystemClock`.

Comment: Do you use a ```SurfaceTexture``` in your callback? If so, you can use the ```getTimestamp()``` method.